# Windows 10 user autologin password lost

Tags: password-cracking, windows-10

A while ago I have set up the autologin for my Windows 10 user.
I do not know the password anymore.
I can login to the system (as has autologin now). But I cannot change the password.

Is it possible to find out what the password was?

This is a Local account and not a Microsoft-account

Comment: Is there another account in the system for which you know the password? If that other account is admin of the machine, you can use it to reset a password. If not, the blessed way is to re-install the system (after all you are trying to enter somewhere without the key...). If you do not want to go that way, you could google for *lost password windows*

Comment: No other account. Re-installation is ok but do not solve the problem if next time occur. I just wonder how this function is working. The autologin must save a copy of your password somewhere on the computer. I wonder if this function store/protect/Encrypt the password in the same way that windows does ( SAM and SYSTEM files)